# animations on html page load

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I want to do the same animation effect on html div blocks as in the website http://rpglobal.ae/ -> About us section. Kindly let me know which jquery and css I need to use to achieve this.
Thanks

Comment: the animation effect as in the images on the about us section.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ - more specifically `slideInRight` and `slideInLeft`. I'm using this in my work from along a time, it's very easy to implement and looks very good (also on mobiles).

Here you can find documentation and source code https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I want to have fadeIn zoomIn and slideInRight all three of them combined together into a smooth transition. How can i achieve this,

Comment: That's, if I'm right, not possible. Unfortunately you may choose only one effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need just to set a class in css like `".effect"` and get it a `"transform: translateX"` like this.

```
.about_us {
transform: translateX(20%);
transition: transform .3s ease;
}
.effect {
transform: translate(0);
}
```

Then with JavaScript, you can tell it when the panel has been loaded, add class name `"effect"` to the class name `"about_us"` and it will work with a transition.

For its JavaScript:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('about_us').item(0);
elem.addEventListener('load', eff, false);

function eff() {
elem.classList.add('effect');
}
```

Comment: In the CSS block, why are there quotes at the beginning and end - is this in a JavaScript string? If this is just a CSS file or style block then these will just produce syntax errors.

Comment: hi, i checked the source code. It uses  <img src="cms_images/csr_29102014065604img4.jpg" class="img-full" data-anim="" data-anim-delay="200" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0rad) skewX(0rad) scale(1, 1);">

Comment: please suggest how do i use it on my <div> The website reference is http://rpglobal.ae/ -> CSR Activities

Comment: @SubhasreeMazumder you can use any transform property such as rotate, skew, translate , or... .

Comment: @halfer no, it is just for quote.

Comment: I have edited your post again. Please note we are scrupulously fair to all religious faiths here: we prefer posts not to contain material from any of them, [read more here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295810). If you wish to proselytise, you can do it in your profile, or on your blog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use all of 'transform' properties such as rotate, translate, skew or... . For this purpose, use this style for the first style of the element (for example):

```
transform: rotate(90deg) skew(10deg) translate(20px);
```

Then when the js code on 'load' event works, you can set all these properties on 0.

```
transform: rotate(0) skew(0) translate(0);
```

That's it. for changing the effect, you need to change the properties of first css style of the element.

The website "http://rpglobal.ae/" for its images has uses 'scale' property and for its right panel has uses 'translate' property. so you can add 2 class styles to your CSS file, and then add each one to your divs (images and your text panel).